# npm install error. node js? fsevents? Xcode? Or another problem?

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, npm-install, fsevents

Good afternoon. Friends! Help please. There was an error. I run the `npm install` command and this problem crashes:

```
natalakolivosko@192 webpack-static-template % npm install

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/natalakolivosko/Documents/JM/wc_CPS_block16/webpack-static-template/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/natalakolivosko/Documents/JM/wc_CPS_block16/webpack-static-template/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/natalakolivosko/Documents/JM/wc_CPS_block16/webpack-static-template/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/natalakolivosko/Documents/JM/wc_CPS_block16/webpack-static-template/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 

> node-sass@4.14.1 install /Users/natalakolivosko/Documents/JM/wc_CPS_block16/webpack-static-template/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at /Users/natalakolivosko/.npm/node-sass/4.14.1/darwin-x64-72_binding.node

> node-sass@4.14.1 postinstall /Users/natalakolivosko/Documents/JM/wc_CPS_block16/webpack-static-template/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /Users/natalakolivosko/Documents/JM/wc_CPS_block16/webpack-static-template/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-72/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
npm WARN webpack-test@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 959 packages from 489 contributors and audited 959 packages in 27.986s

28 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 215 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

I tried to uninstall and install again `node js` with [link](https://www.positronx.io/how-to-uninstall-node-js-and-npm-from-macos/). I also tried installing `fsevents` again via `npm install fsevents`.

Unfortunately, this did not lead to any results.

Please tell me what the problem is and how to FIX it?

If you have any further questions, please let me know and I will answer them.

p.s. I have macOS.

Comment: This could be an issue with npm/node version. and install nodejs with nvm

Comment: I managed, it helped to reinstall Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao, according to [this](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detected-macos-catalina-anansewaa-38b536389e8d) article, you have to reinstall command-line tools by removing the previous installed version. In brief:

1. Find location where command-line tools is installed:

   ```
    xcode-select --print-path
   ```
2. Remove it:

   ```
   sudo rm -r -f /path/found/onprevious/step
   ```
3. Reinstall it:

   ```
   xcode-select --install
   ```

Note: article is referring to macOS Catalina.

Comment: Yes thank you dear friend. I found this article myself yesterday and solved the problem. But thank you, because if I hadn't found this article, your answer would have helped me. Thanks!))

Comment: No problem. Happy to ear you solve it. Have a nice day :)